# Office Addin - Specifying requirement tags for two different hosts (ExcelApi, WordApi)

Tags: ms-office, add-in, office-js

I have a problem when submitting my Addin for Office

My plugin must work on Word and Excel 2016 (MS Desktop 2016, Online, Mac). When I submitted, they told me that all must be in one project.

This is about the 4.12.1 chapter about extension exigence page, when I wanted to put the "requirements" tags.

So, I put these lines, but the plugin didn't work. Only "WordApi" or "ExcelApi" is allowed but not the both. In the furnished manifest, I put only WordApi.

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
        <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.2"/>
        <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

I spent one day to search everywhere but nothing. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue here is using a single manifest for both Word and Excel. If you specify both 'Document' and 'Workbook as hosts but then add WordApi as a requirement it will effectively disable your add-in in Excel. This is because Excel will always fail the requirement check for for WordApi. Similarly, if you specify ExcelApi it will effectively disable the add-in for Word.

The workaround is to create two manifest files, one for each host. Note that this will require that you submit two different add-ins for validation since each add-in is linked to a single manifest.

When submitting multiple add-ins there are a couple of important steps that need to be taken:

- Each add-in must have a unique name. You cannot submit two add-ins with the same name as it would make it pretty difficult for user's to discern between them. As an aside, *descriptive names are super important*. I cannot overstate how much better add-ins with descriptive names perform over add-ins that rely only on brand/product names.
- Each manifest must have a unique GUID `<id>` in the manifest. This is how Office identifies each add-ins (Names may change change but Ids remain the same) and submitting two add-ins with the same Id will trigger an error condition. Even in side-loaded scenarios, duplicate Ids will present problems when deploying.
- Validation isn't an automated process, it involves human beings actually testing your add-in. Providing as much detail as possible will help them get up to speed quickly so they can focus on helping you get into the Store.

Comment: Agreed with Marc (though, as he points out, it does have the unfortunate disadvantage of requiring two separate store entities, one for each host).  In other words, requirement sets can only be AND-ed, not OR-ed.  Let me reach out to the team to see how common of a scenario this is, and if we perhaps can do something about it...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick answer.

You were exactly right. We must publish 2 different addins.
However, I tried to do that at first. But the validation team refused it. They want one addin for all host. Then I did an addin for both hosts.

Comment: I've added some tips to my original answer. That said, please take Phil up on his offer and email the validation team directly. We would love to resolve your issue so we can share that guidance back to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marc,

I understand now. At the begining, when I submited my 2 addins, they should have been the same Id and the same name, which involved an error.

Now, I will divide my addin into 2 diffents addins: one for Word and the other one for Word.

Have a good day!